# Is there a way of getting only the issues without a certain label using the GitHub Api

Tags: github, github-api, github-for-windows

I have the following

```
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \ 
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/issues?labels=label
```

Currently I am only able to get the issues that have a certain label using the GitHub api, is there a way to get all the issues that doesn’t have a specific label using the GitHub api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on github [DOC](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues#list-repository-issues), It's not possible

```
labels                             string
A list of comma separated label names. Example: bug,ui,@high
```

One solution would be to implement it. You can get all the issue then iterate using a loop to remove  the issue that has the specific label

Comment: Would this perhaps be possible using the GitHub graph API?